# Receiving 401 Unauthorized response when trying to retrieve collection from firestore in Ionic / Angular app

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

In my firestore, I have a `users` collection. The below code is the `Users Service` in my Ionic / Angular app.

`fetchUsers()` is meant to retrieve all `user` documents:

```
private _users = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>([]);

  get users() {
    return this._users.asObservable();
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  fetchUsers() {
    return this.http
      .get<{ [key: string]: UserData }>('https://myFirebaseUrl.firebaseio.com/users.json')
      .pipe(map(resData => {
        const users = [];
        for (const key in resData) {
          if (resData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            users.push(
              new User(
                key,
                resData[key].name)
            );
          }
        }
        return users;
      }),
        tap(users => {
          this._users.next(users);
        })
      );
  }
```

However, when this method is called I get the below console error:

Can someone please tell me why I'm unauthorized to make this call & what changes are required in my code to make this work?

[image]

Here are the current Database Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone on the internet to view, edit, and delete
    // all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // your app will lose access to your Firestore database
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 7, 5);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how are you authenticating?

Comment: Hi @drum I've updated my question with how I'm authenticating. I have a `login` page that uses firebase auth to sign in users. If login is successful, then the user is navigated to the page that calls `fetchUsers()`

Comment: i meant how are you authenticating to firebase?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _authenticating to firebase_

Comment: Do your security rules allow access to the user collection?

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) which explaing what everyone is asking above. Basically it might be that your users are not allowed to read the contents of that collection. Which also makes sense as you do not all users getting all the info about other users. Instead, you can give access to your server and handle things there, or simply use strict rules to avoid privacy issues. (Keep in mind if you have users in EU, privacy should be taken seriously due to GDPR).

Comment: Hi @Waelmas I have updated my question with the current database rules

Comment: Your rules look okay to me. I'd say try to  set the configuartion again (Firebase project config) as it might fix it. It could be a random underlying issue or something that went wrong at the app side.